# Convert Dart List of Double or Int to List of String

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, arraylist

I have:

`List<double> prices = [20.5, 10.0, 18.6, 41.8];`

I need as Parameter Value:

`pricesString : ["20.5", "10.0", "18.6", "41.8"],`

Comment: If there is **EXACT SAME** question then let me know, I'll delete this one.

Comment: and by what sense do you want to convert a double to a string?

Comment: @OMiShah Because one parameter in my program is asking for a string list but I've double list in JSON. and I wanted to declare _directly to the parameter_ value instead of juggling with variables.

Comment: then why don't you change the method/function/class's parameter type instead of creating another list !!

Comment: @OMiShah because it's from a third-party flutter package which I didn't want to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pricesString : prices.map((e) => e.toString()).toList(),`

Which is passing the following list:

`pricesString : ["20.5", "10.0", "18.6", "41.8"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> prices = List.generate(firtList.length,(i) => firtList[i].toString());
```